# numpy dependencies thrown an error when importing pandas to my python project

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, anaconda

I have got the following traceback error when importing pandas. I have installed all packages using anaconda3 distribution and also verified everything seems alright. When I use conda search numpy on command prompt also returns the installed packages. But if I try to import pandas as pd it throws an error.(numpy: No module named 'logging.handlers'; 'logging' is not a package) Need some guidance here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: No module named 'logging.handlers'; 'logging' is not a package
```

Comment: Do you have by any chance a file named `logging.py` in the same folder - if so renaming would solve the issue. Can you edit your question and also include the output of `python -c "import logging; print(logging)"`

Answer (score 0):

I have a `logging.py` file on my project directory. After renaming the file also returns following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

After changing the entire project to a new directory resolves the issue.